# Remove swapped duplicated row using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an id pairs in 2 columns. There are some pairs which are redundant, but in a swapped form. How can i removed redundant id pairs using Excel?

Here is the explanation,

Initial,

```
col1 col2
id1  id2
id2  id1
id3  id8
id1  id5
id1  id6
id2  id9
```

Need to be like,

```
col1 col2
id1  id2
id3  id8
id1  id5
id1  id6
id2  id9
```

(Note that the 2nd row id2 id1 is deleted, because it is a swapped duplicate).

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

1.Write two max min functions in the as a excel function adjacent to these 2 cells(maxa did not work for some reason)

2.copy values only to some other place and remove duplicates.

[image: same function is pasted in the lower cells]

ps: I tried to transpose then sort transpose back, but it tries to sort as one big record rather than tuples. Hence the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following steps:-

Join them together in the right order into column C

```
=IF(A2<B2,A2&"|"&B2,B2&"|"&A2)
```

Find the unique values in column D (array formula must be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter))

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$7, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $C$2:$C$7), 0)),"")
```

Separate the first one in Column E

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(D2,FIND("|",D2)-1),"")
```

Separate the second one in column F

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-FIND("|",D2)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dealing with Column A and B with a header in each column, I'd do this put cell C2 and drag down. Delete anything greater than 0:

```
    =COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,A2,$A$2:A2,B2)
```

To clarify what's happening here, the $ in the ranges act as anchors when you drag down. So making the range from $B$2:B2 means the next cell down will be $B$2:B3 followed by $B$2:B4 and so on.

The COUNTIFS() formula returns a count where ALL the criteria are met, so only those rows with both values switched are counted.

Using the COUNTIFS() with the anchored range like I've done here only counts whatever comes above that row, which is why you can delete any non-zeros without losing the unique values.

I'd recommend verifying this in case there's something I didn't think of, of course.